# How to get the field values in react material ui components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This works but the when i console log the object it gives

{ "week":*undefined*, "name":*undefined*, "code":*undefined* }

Moreover does wrapping all the material ui component in form tag and treating the whole code as a form, is it appropriate?
here is my code:

```
const ExamSimulatorForm = () => {
    const weekNumber = useRef();
    const examSub = useRef();
    const examCode = useRef();


    const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()
        const week = weekNumber.current.value
        const subject = examSub.current.value
        const code = examCode.current.value

        const examSimulatorPayload = {
            week:week,
            subject:subject,
            code:code
        }
        console.log(examSimulatorPayload)
    }
const [code, setCode] = useState('Quiz');
    const [examSubject, setExamSubject] = useState('');
    const [field, setField] = useState(1)

 

 
  const handleESubjectChange = (event) => {
    setExamSubject(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleCode = (event) => {
    setCode(event.target.value);
  };




    return (
        <form >
        <CardActions onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            
            <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent='center' alignItems='center' direction='column'>
            <Grid item>
                <TextField 
                 InputProps={{
                    inputProps: { 
                        max: 12, min: 1 
                    }
                }}
                label='Week'
                type='number'
                onChange={(event)=>setField(parseInt(event.target.value))}
                style={{minWidth:250}}
                ref = {weekNumber}
                required
                  />
                
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                <FormControl style={{minWidth:250}}>
                    <InputLabel>Subject</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            value={examSubject}
                            onChange={handleESubjectChange}
                            ref={examSub}
                            required
                            >
                            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                <FormControl style={{minWidth:250}}>
                    <InputLabel id="exam-code" >Exam Code</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                           labelId="exam-code"
                             id="exam-code-select"
                            value={code}
                            onChange={handleCode}
                            ref={examCode}
                            required
                            >
                            <MenuItem value={'Q'}>Q</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'M'}>M</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'F'}>F</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button variant='contained' color='primary' style={{marginTop:94}} >Take Exam</Button>
                </Grid>       
            </Grid>
        </CardActions>
        </form>
     
    )
}



export default ExamSimulatorForm;
```

I have a similar form for attendance simulation, attendance dataset generation and exam dataset generation

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good for you.
Please try this.

```
const ExamSimulatorForm = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
       code: 'Quiz',
       subject: '',
       week: 1
    });

    const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()

        const examSimulatorPayload = state;

        console.log(examSimulatorPayload)
    }

    const handleChange = (evt, name) {
        const { value } = evt.target;
        setState({
            ...state,
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <CardActions>
            <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent='center' 
              alignItems='center' direction='column'>
            <Grid item>
                <TextField 
                 InputProps={{
                    inputProps: { 
                        max: 12, min: 1 
                    }
                }}
                label='Week'
                type='number'
                value={state.week}
                onChange={(event)=>handleChange( event, "week")}
                style={{minWidth:250}}
                required
                  />
                
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                <FormControl style={{minWidth:250}}>
                    <InputLabel>Subject</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            value={state.subject}
                            onChange={(event)=>handleChange( event, "subject")}
                            required
                            >
                            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                <FormControl style={{minWidth:250}}>
                    <InputLabel id="exam-code" >Exam Code</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                           labelId="exam-code"
                             id="exam-code-select"
                            value={state.code}
                            onChange={(event)=>handleChange( event, "code")}
                            required
                            >
                            <MenuItem value={'Q'}>Q</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'M'}>M</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={'F'}>F</MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button variant='contained' color='primary' style= 
                      {{marginTop:94}} >Take Exam</Button>
                </Grid>       
            </Grid>
        </CardActions>
        </form>
     
    )
}



export default ExamSimulatorForm;
```

Please check it above code, and let me know your idea.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it worked. Can i use it on datefields also?

Comment: you mean in the `<TextField type="date" />`?

Comment: You can use all fields that have `onChange` and `value`.
If you have any other problems, I'll help you anytime.

Answer (score 0):

State updates in react are asynchronus, which means they don't occur as soon as you call them. You have to wait until the state updates to console.log because otherwise, nothing has changed and you are getting the initial value. You could do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const subject = examSub.current.value
     console.log(subject)
    }, [examSubject])
```

useEffect() executes an action every time a state changes. Notice how at the end there is an array, with [examSubject]. This signifies the state that will trigger the effect. So when examSubject changes (when you assign a value to it), the effect will execute (in this case, it will log the subject).

When writing code, at least in my case, you don't need to worry about this. You can chnage the state and write your code as normal, but react might take a second or two to update the state. The only time I really notice this is when I console.log.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the state for your inputs :

```
  const [code, setCode] = React.useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = React.useState('');
  const [week, setWeek] = React.useState('');

 const setExamCode = event => {
    setCode(event.target.value);
  };

 const setSubject = event => {
     setSubject(event.target.value);
  };

 const setWeek = event => {
    setWeek(event.target.value);
  };

Then call these methods from onChange event like : onChange={setExamCode} or {setSubject}
```

In case you want to handle data from single event and defining it's initial state try below approach :

```
const initialData = Object.freeze({
    code: "",
    subject: "",
    week: ""
 });

const [data, updateData] = React.useState(initialData );

const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateData({
      ...data,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Then call these methods from onChange event like onChange={handleSubmit}